# DFDL Schema for parsing delimited text message

Tags: xsd, dfdl

Need small help for DFDL. I need to parse below message as something like XML/tree structure. Elements are not fixed and dynamic. Sometime some other elements will appear.

[image]

XML/Tree output expected as something below

```
<root>
<CLIENT_ID>DESKTOPCLIENT</CLIENT_ID>
<LOCALE>en-US</LOCALE>
<ENCODE/>
</root>
```

Comment: Standard rules apply on this site: you need supply details of what you have tried. Please supply the DFDL schema that you are using (remove anything that is private) and supply the input bitstream as a BLOB (you have supplied an image from your text viewer).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is a possible solution, tested in Daffodil:

```html
<xs:schema
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:dfdl="http://www.ogf.org/dfdl/dfdl-1.0/">

  <xs:include schemaLocation="org/apache/daffodil/xsd/DFDLGeneralFormat.dfdl.xsd" />

  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="http://www.ogf.org/dfdl/">
      <dfdl:format
        ref="GeneralFormat"
        lengthKind="delimited"
      />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>

  <xs:element name="root" dfdl:initiator="%ESC;" dfdl:terminator="%SUB;">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence dfdl:separator="%CAN;" dfdl:separatorPosition="prefix" dfdl:sequenceKind="unordered">
        <xs:element name="CLIENT_ID" type="xs:string" dfdl:initiator="CLIENT_ID%NAK;" />
        <xs:element name="LOCALED" type="xs:string" dfdl:initiator="LOCALE%NAK;" />
        <xs:element name="ENCODE" type="xs:string" dfdl:initiator="ENCODE%NAK;" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Note that this assumes fixed names for the individual elements, and that they all exist, though the order does not matter. If you know the fixed names, but they may or may not exist, you can add `minOccurs="0"` to the elements in the unorderd sequence.

However, DFDL does not allow for dynami element names, so if you don't know the names, you need a slightly different schema. Instead, you need to describe the data as an unbouned number of name/value pairs, where the name and value are separated by %NAK;, for example:

```html
  <xs:element name="root" dfdl:initiator="%ESC;" dfdl:terminator="%SUB;">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence dfdl:separator="%CAN;" dfdl:separatorPosition="prefix">
        <xs:element name="element" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence dfdl:separator="%NAK;" dfdl:separatorPosition="infix">
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

This results in an infoset that looks something like this:

```html
<root>
  <element>
    <name>CLIENT_ID</name>
    <value>DESKTOPCLIENT</value>
  </element>
  <element>
    <name>LOCALE</name>
    <value>en-US</value>
  </element>
  <element>
    <name>ENCODE</name>
    <value></value>
  </element>
</root>
```

If you need the XML tags to match the name fields like in your question, you would then need to transform the infoset. XSLT can do this kind of transformation without much trouble.

Edit: There seems to be an issue where IBM DFDL does not like the above solution. I'm not sure why, but it works with Apache Daffodil. Something about value being the empty string causes an issue. After some trial and error, I've found that IBM DFDL (and Apache Daffodil too) are okay with it if you specify that empty value elements should be treated as nil. So changing the value element to this works:

```html
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" nillable="true"
  dfdl:nilKind="literalValue" dfdl:nilValue="%ES;"
  dfdl:useNilForDefault="no"/>
```

In that case, the infoset ends up with something like this:

```html
<element>
  <name>ENCODE</name>
  <value xsi:nil="true"></value>
</element>
```

Edit2: The nillable properties are required because otherwise IBM DFDL treats an empty string value as absent rather than having an empty value. Being absent results in the error. Newer versions of the DFDL spec add a new property, `emptyElementParsePolicy`, which lets you control whether or not empty strings are treated as absent or are just treated as an empty string. Daffodil implements this property as an extensions, but defaults to the treat as empty behavior. IBM DFDL has the treat as absent behavior. Daffodil has a similar behavior to IBM DFDL when setting this property to treat as absent.

Comment: Unfortunately appearance of elements like CLIENT_ID, LOCALE, in message is not bounded. It can be there or may be not. Sometime, some other elements will appear. Can we have regex in terminator field which mention terminator as start of %ESC or %NAK. I mean it can take value until these characters occurs.

Comment: You can do a regex, but it's likely more efficient and clear to use a separator, and make the schema a bit more generic. I've updated the answer based on these clarifications.

Comment: Hi @stevedlawrence, I am able to get only first name,value pair. DFDL parsing completes with an error. fatal: CTDP3062E: An unexpected non-postfix separator '' occurs in a postfix position at offset '49' in 'sequence' group contained within element 'root', xpath: '/root[1]'.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with IBM DFDL, the above works with Apache Daffodil. I'm not sure why IBM DFDL doesn't like it, but I've edited the end of the answer to provide a workaround for IBM DFDL.